# XCode - Runner - cannot select device emulator

Tags: ios, macos, flutter

I want to start by saying that I'm new to macOS and I'm sorry if this question is wrong formulated.
So, I have a mobile app wrote in Flutter. I open the Runner file from the terminal with: open ios/Runner.xcworkspace and XCode shows up. My problem is that where I should select the device where I want my application to be built, the only option is : Any iOS Device.
[image]

So, I thought that I do not have any simulators installed on this machine, but I do. This is what I have installed (Window->Devices and Simulators):

[image]

When I try to run my code with "Any iOS Device" selected this problem occurs:
[image]

I don't know what to do in order to run my app on one of these devices.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to click on that Any iOS Device area:

[image]

And then just choose the device/simulator you want to test on:

[image]

Comment: I've tried to click on that option but sadly nothing shows up.

Comment: Then what about Product>Destination from top ribbon?

Comment: @RaduHrihoreanu could you show me the "General" pane of your Runner Project?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in order to fix this, I had to go to my project setting -> build settings and change Supported Platforms values to iOS (it was macOS selected).
[image]